# Testing Java Socket Communication with Multiple Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, testing

We have an application which communicates with sensors using Modbus/TCP protocol. For every sensor a thread is responsible for socket communication. We want to test the app for 200 sensors, but actually do not own that many sensor-hardware. Can anyone suggest a simulation mechanism to test our app ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you write a dummy client which does the same thing, unless you can find one on the internet or the vendor of the sensors has one.

This will be useful for more than just load testing. You should be able to create a few thousand connections per desktop or on the server.

Comment: I'd add the suggestion to build into those clients the possibility not only to behave correctly but also to configure them to simulate "errors". Like broken hardware sending nonsense values ... or randomly ending the connection etc.

Comment: @Fildor good point, testing for broken clients is very useful, such as one which spams the server with too much data.

Comment: Thank you Peter Lawrey, @Fildor  for the suggestions. My doubt here is that for simulating 200 sensors, won't we be requiring 200 systems running the sensor-simulator, since the socket communication is based on IP address & port number ? Here the port number which are using is constant.

Comment: "Here the port number which are using is constant." Is it because you do not change port numbers of the sensors or because *cannot* change them? If you have to use one single port for all sensors and your software does not support using different ports, you might have a chance in using virtualization?

Comment: @Fildor or make it that the software can support different ports on a small number of hosts instead.

Comment: @Fildor we are using the same port because Modbus uses 502 & I believe it cannot be changed. Also tne IP address given to each sensor will be static throughout. We assumed that in order to replicate the actual scenario of our application we may need 200 number of systems communicating via 502 port & having unique static IPs. Is there any alternative to avoid using 200 systems ?

Comment: @Sathiya you don't need to change the port on your sensor, you only need to change the port on the software which connects to the sensor.  This should be either a) easy to change or b) possible to hack, if it is written in Java. If it's written in C and you don't have the source, you should be able to write a connector in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey are you suggesting to use the same system to run the sensor-simulator & use different ports for each sensor-simulator ?

Comment: @Sathiya correct. Although one sensor simulator could use 1000 ports if you wish. If you aggregator connects to the sensor, you don't even need to give them different ports.  Just configure 1000 connections all the same and it will create that many connections using the same IP & port.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you. We will try out what you have suggested & get back to you. Thank you..